# Search all .pst files in network

Tags: powershell

```
$computers = net view
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    Get-ChildItem -Resurse *.pst
}
```

I wasn't sure how to search `\\PC\c$` using this and would that even work like that?

Comment: Have you tried? Did it not work? Are you getting an error? What does it say? Is `-Resurse` a typo in your question or in your actual script? Do you have administrative privileges (required for access to administrative shares)?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the admin shares (you need admin privileges to access them). Syntax is `\\hostname\drive$\folder` (example: `\\MYMachineName\c$\MyFolder`).

If you want to search for `pst` files in `C` drive:

```
net view | ForEach-Object {
    $CDrivePath = ($_.Trim()) + "\C$"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $CDrivePath -Recurse -Filter "*.pst"
}
```

But beware that the command would be time consuming, you may want to narrow down your search area rather than searching the entire computer.